# Solve $\frac{dy}{dx} + 4y = 5 \sin 3x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{dy}{dx} + 4y = 5 \sin 3x$$
It is already in standard form, so our integrating factor is:
$$v(x) = e^{\int{4dx}}=e^{4x}$$
$$\frac{d}{dx} y \cdot e^{4x} = 5 \sin3x$$
$$y = \int {(5e^{-4x} \cdot \sin 3x)dx}$$
$$y = 5\int {(e^{-4x} \cdot \sin 3x)dx}$$
Well, that integral looks badly. I heard there is other metod which uses "guessing" the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding what you've heard, yes, there's a method with ``guessing'', and it involves, hm, guessing :) But first, you solve homogeneous part of the problem
$$
y' + 4y = 0
$$
which has a solution $y = C e^{-4x}$.

Now, you need to guess a particular (any solution that satisfies the equation) solution. Looking at the right hand side, you might guess it as $y_p = A \sin 3x + B \cos 3x$. Now substitute it to the equation,
$$
3A \cos 3x  - 3B \sin 3x + 4A\sin 3x + 4B\cos 3x = (3A + 4B) \cos 3x + (4A - 3B) \sin 3x = 5\sin 3x
$$
from which you can conclude that
$$
3A + 4B = 0 \\
4A - 3B = 5
$$
or
$$
A = \frac 45 \\
B = -\frac 35
$$
and finally
$$
y_p = \frac 45 \sin 3x -\frac 35 \cos 3x
$$
Now, you use principle of superposition to make a final conclusion, that the general solution of the problem given is
$$
y = C e^{-4x} + \frac 45 \sin 3x -\frac 35 \cos 3x
$$

Comment: I made some algebraic mistake... Fixing it.

Comment: Hopefully fixed it.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a general name of method you used?

Comment: Try "the method of undetermined coefficients".

Comment: @SimonRose at least that what I was taught. But google gives exactly this name for the method above. So, disregard my previous comment. If it's widely used under that name, then why not. It's just a matter of convention.

Answer (score 2):

Try following: solution of each differential equation can be split in two parts - natural response  and particular response (RHS of your equation). Natural response is the one that you get while solving with RHS=0, and the particular response or solution can be guessed like this:

Assumption: $y_{natural}=Ce^{rx}$ where r denotes the solution of algebraic equation you get with RHS=0:

$\frac{d(Ce^{rx})}{dx}+4Ce^{rx}=0 $

$Cre^{rx}+4Ce^{rx}=0 /:Ce^{rx}$

$r+4=0$

$r=-4$

$y_{natural}=Ce^{-4x}$

excitation function: $=5sin(3x)$ so try with:

$y_{particular}=Asin(3x)+Bcos(3x)$, take care that $y_{particular}$ and  $y_{natural}$ must

be linearly independent - can't sum them up!

now calculate:

$y_{particular}=Asin(3x)+Bcos(3x)$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=3Acos(3x)-3Bsin(3x)$

put them in your equation and you get:

$3Acos(3x)-3Bsin(3x)+4Asin(3x)+4Bcos(3x)=5sin(3x)$

$(-3B+4A)sin(3x)+(3A+4B)cos(3x)=5sin(3x)$

and you get an A/\B system of equs:

$-3B+4A=5$

$3A+4B=0$

solving this you get:

$B=\frac{-3}{5}$

$A=\frac{4}{5}$

and finally:

$y_{particular}=\frac{4}{5}sin(3x)-\frac{3}{5}cos(3x)$

your total solution is now:

$y_{total}=y_{particular}+y_{natural}$

and that's about it.

Answer (score 1):

This integral isn't nearly as bad as it looks. Integrate by parts twice to solve it.